# Display Gridviews with data at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in C#.Net and have a page with five gridviews. Once I run the application, all the five grids should be displayed with data at a time. But now, one by one is loading and displaying.

How to display all the gridview at a time? Whether I should do anything in page render.

Here is my Page_Load..

```
gridview1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
gridview1.DataBind();
gridview2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
gridview2.DataBind();
gridview3.DataSource = ds3.Tables[0];
gridview3.DataBind();
gridview4.DataSource = ds4.Tables[0];
gridview4.DataBind();
gridview5.DataSource = ds5.Tables[0];
gridview5.DataBind();
```

First two grids had less amount of data. so it got quickly laoded in the output page. when coming to 3rd grid, it had large amount of data, at that time the output page looks with first two gridviews and waiting for the 3rd grid.

What i want is, once i run the application all the five grids should get displayed at a time..

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: how do you bind data to gridview

Comment: getting the data through dataset and binding that dataset to datasource and gridview1.databind();

Comment: i want to show all the gridviews at one shot..while running the application

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? MVC? please add another tag to your question

Comment: yes i had updated my question..

Comment: are you binding all gridviews in one method(like Page_Load)

Comment: yes..i am doing like this only...

Comment: try loading the 5 gridviews with a small amount of data in each, then make sure you aren't swallowing any exceptions - what you are doing should work.

Comment: its working..tats not an issue...there is time difference for loading the gridviews..i want the grid should get preloaded and once the output page comes, all the grids should displaed.

Comment: It is the way the Web Pages are transferred from Server to browser. It is transferred in Chunks. Only thing you can do is to apply paging for the grids so that only small amount of data is loaded in each grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the datasource on each gridview and databind each gridview.

there is no need to do anything in page render.

you will not get an answer for this until you can show what you are doing - and the only way to do that is to post an example of your markup / code

Answer (score 0):

5 grids = 5 datasources. Do you have them?